# macOS Server: How to sign enrollment profiles?

Tags: osx-server, code-signing, automated-device-enrollment

I am wondering how to sign enrollment profiles for macOS Server. Ideally, I would like to avoid paying money. In any case, how do you do it?

Comment: Are you sure macOS's normal [creation steps](https://support.apple.com/guide/profile-manager/create-an-enrollment-profile-pmd6dd5e89e/mac) don't sign the profile?

Comment: Yes. From my first-hand experience and the first sentence in that article says "Use enrollment profiles to quickly add managed devices without users needing to sign in and enroll the devices." So to the best of my knowledge and according to that article enrollment profiles are NOT signed by default.

Comment: Not sure if enrollment profiles are different, but I sign all our profiles using `/usr/bin/security cms -S` with a self-signed certificate. Is that an option for you?